# Scope Issue returning JSON and Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

i have a some data i'd like to spit out on a map with json. the markers are plotted out, so i know it's scoping there, which is why i'm struggling with this. the data is overwriting each other.

infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0], locations[i][6]);

that will only show the vars for locations[i][6];, overwriting locations[i][0].

i'm pretty sure it's a scope issue, but i could be way off. i threw it up here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/pGBZD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `setContent` method only takes one argument](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow).

> setContent(content:string|Node)

Any additional arguments will be ignored. If you want to include both location indices in your pop-up bubble, you can try this:

```
infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + '<br>' + locations[i][6]);
```